# How to export a XLSX file with fiex location?

Tags: angularjs, js-xlsx, sheetjs

I was tasked to develop an application that reads an xlsx file on a determined directory, and also it exports a generated XLSX file into this same directory. The problem is, the directory's set but using js-xlsx I can't avoid my application from showing the window to select the location, is there a way to prevent this? here's the code of the service I created

```
services.saveXlsxFile = function(sales){
    var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(sales);
    var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "Totals");
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, "file.xlsx");
}
```

Thanks for helping!